# Slow convergence of Stokes solver used with the Immersed Boundary method

Tags: iterative-method, navier-stokes

I am using Immersed Boundary Method to simulate elastic particles in 3D Stokes flow. Specifically, one has $\nabla ^2 \mathbf{u}-\nabla p + \mathbf{f}(t) = 0$, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \; $, where $\mathbf{f} (t)$ is calculated based on instantaneous configuration of some particle assembly that is advected by flow $\mathbf{u}$. More explicitly, $ \dot{\mathbf{r}}_i = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}_i) \;$, $\mathbf{f}(t)=\mathcal{F}(\{\mathbf{r}_i\})$, $\mathcal{F}$ denoting some function(al) that depends on all $\mathbf{r}_i$:s.

Within the Immersed Boundary Method, $\mathbf{u}$ is discretized on a spatial (non-moving) grid. To simulate a time step, one first solves a discretized linear system to obtain $\mathbf{u}$ for a given instantaneous value of $\mathbf{f}$, then moves particles at their positions $\mathbf{r}_i$:s with the velocity of the flow at those positions: $\mathbf{r}_i (t+\delta t) = \mathbf{r}_i (t) + \delta t \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}_i,t) $. Finally, one updates $\mathbf{f}$ according to the newly obtained values of $\mathbf{r}_i$:s.

Broadly, I can see two ways of dealing with Stokes dynamics: 
(1) The method described above, requiring to solve a large linear system in every step. 
(2) Simulating transient flow by adding $\rho \partial _t \mathbf{u}$ term and artificial compressibility to the equation.

In my hands, using method (1) is slow since it requires solving a linear system in every time-step. I use iterative MINRES solver implemented in PETSc, but the number of iterations to reach convergence tends to be large (some 4000). 
Method (2) does not require solving a linear system, but introduces a small parameter which degrades accuracy unless the parameter is made really small (requiring small time step).

My question is twofold: 
(1) Using method (1), I do recycle my solution from a previous time-step as an initial guess for the iterative solver. Yet, typically, the number of iterations required seems large (~4000). Am I doing something wrong? 
(2) If using method (2), is there some "clever" way to correct for non-zero inertia and obtain something closer to the limit of zero Reynolds? Perhaps something based on a combination of both strategies?

Comment: MINRES is a Krylov subspace method, and for those methods, the quality of the initial guess doesn't matter (unless it is really bad or it is one-order around the stopping tolerance). What you should take a look at is preconditioners. I am not familiar with Immersed boundary method but block preconditioners usually do well for Stokes equations, for example, see "Fast Iterative Solution of Stabilised Stokes Systems Part II: Using General Block Preconditioners" by Silvester and Wathen.